# NetworkManager changes default routing policy

Tags: debian, routing, networkmanager

I have a machine with a built-in NIC (eth0), which serves as a DHCP server for a  Raspberry Pi. I also have a USB 3G modem, which shows up as ethernet device eth1. eth0 has the static ip 192.168.100.1 in `/etc/network/interfaces`.
When I connect the Pi to the server, `/var/log/syslog` shows

```
NetworkManager[2366]: <info> Policy set 'Ifupdown (eth0)' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
```

and after, `ip route show` gives

```
default via 192.168.1.100 dev eth0  proto static
```

I then need to manually

```
ip route delete default
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

to get it to connect to the internet via the 3G modem again.
I am using CrunchBang Linux, based on Debian 7 wheezy, on the server, and the latest Raspbian on the Pi.

How can I choose the default pathway for NetworkManager to prefer?

Edit: here's my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.100.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Note that I've changed `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to have

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

because I want to be able to disconnect eth1, the 3G Modem, using nm-applet.
Here's `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Comment: Don't you have two default routes at some point?

Comment: `ip route show` only ever shows one default route. What I'd like to know is, where does NetworkManager define its preferred route - which keeps overriding my manual setting.

Comment: In connections. It's either in gui, accessible through nmcli, or under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In the nm-applet GUI, I have entries for both wired connections, with eth0 listed as `ifupdown (eth0)`. The problem is that when connected, this connection will cause nm-applet to notify "You are now connected to 'ifupdown (eth0)' " and the "Policy set" message to appear in syslog.

Comment: what is the content of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ?

Answer (score 13):

- If using GUI, try checking the "Use only for resources on this connection" checkbox.
- If using the config files (like you are :) ), in the `[ipv4]` section add `never-default=true` .
- If using commandline tools, run `sudo nmcli con mod "connection name" ipv4.never-default yes`

This way you will be able to delete the default route going in the tunnel & add your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot! editing config helped me to make internet open on my wifi, ifmetric did not help. ifmetric not working with network manager?

Comment: That question is a bit offtopic, but it also seems like coming from a time machine. Looks like the latest version of `ifmetric` came out in 2004...

Comment: :-) I've just recently started to use Linux on a regular basis, now trying things found by internet search, some are still valid, some are not... Does there any way to insert line to file in specific section by bash script? I want to write a script to configure my Linux after install automatically next time to suit my needs.

Comment: This is getting completely offtopic now :) I'd suggest checking out corresponding manpages and then IRC channels of `bash` and `sed`.

Comment: You can also do it via cli: `sudo nmcli con mod "connection name" ipv4.never-default yes`

Comment: Thanks @keeshux, couldn't test it right now, but added the CLI version as well.

Answer (score 8):

I'm 4 years late, but I've just spent 12 hours discovering and then fixing this issue. Similar situation here: ARM based Jetson Nano running Linux 4 Tegra kernel and Ubuntu 18.04 OS, with the Ethernet port (eth0) used for a local network and a USB Cellular dongle (eth1) used for Internet.

Symptoms are similar - once the Ethernet cable is plugged in the interface is brought up, then 3 minutes later I get:

> NetworkManager[3773]:   [1562908622.2587] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS

in syslog and the internet connection is dropped.

NetworkManager works in mysterious ways that are difficult to program around - much better suited to having a user sitting in front that can reset things if necessary. I don't have that luxury, so had to make it work.

Ultimately what worked was to set the `ipv4.route-metric` lower (higher priority) on eth1. Check the output of `route -n` to see what the current metrics are. Ignore the additional 20000 on some routes - this is NetworkManager trying to de-prioritise routes that don't have Internet connectivity, but it's screwy.

So say eth0 has a metric of 100. Prioritise your eth1 interface with:

```
sudo nmcli con mod "Wired connection 2" ipv4.route-metric 99
```

And reboot.

Now to save you 10 hours of troubleshooting - note that the route metric is independent of the DNS priority! So if you still have connectivity issues, make sure it's not a DNS resolution issue (eg. your DHCP server is providing a dummy resolution service). If it is, then increase the `ipv4.dns-priority` of your eth0 connection to make it lower priority, and/or make sure the `ipv4.dns-search` of your eth1 is set to "~" to make it the go-to option.

Comment: Really helpful I've been looking for this solution for a few years as well - really nice to have.  In my case I have one wired broadband and one 5G backup via RJ45.  This enables failover as opposed to the accepted option which will never use the secondary connection.

You'd think this should be more obvious in the nm config apps.  Also when restarting NetworkManager after adjusting this I encountered a NM bug where it fails to manage the interface with old priority.  Required a restart in the end as whole network stack was hosed.

Comment: I don't have the certainty to create a full answer about it, but I think these problems are clearly solved, if you properly configure the `Connectivity` feature of NetworkManager (the one where a route gets a lower priority if a pinging to a certain host fails etc.).

Comment: @jriv, something may have changed in the last 2.5 years, but at the time `connectivity` did not help. This is addressed in the answer by the sentence referring to "additional 20000 on some routes". But more importantly, the question was about *preventing* routing policy changes. `connectivity` is specifically designed to change routing policies. Dynamic routing is very bad in certain situations, such as embedded systems or systems relying on mobile broadband connections, so a method to prevent it can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If someone cannot fix the issue with other answers, you may also want to check if you don't have another network manager installed that is interfering.
I had both ConnMan and NetworkManager installed and the issue was fixed after uninstalling ConnMan and rebooting.

This was my issue in details previously:

On Debian 12, even when checking "Use only for resources on this connection" in NetworkManager, the Internet connection stopped working due to route changes after connecting my phone through USB for SSH / SFTP connection so I had to reconnect to network and then was able to use USB and Ethernet at the same time. I also had to reconnect to network after plugging out the USB cable of my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Network manager will always override your settings, You must edit:

vi /etc/network/interfaces

Find the eth0 and set:

```
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Re start network service:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: I did this, but as soon as I connect interface eth0, I get the `NetworkManager[2366]: <info> Policy set 'Ifupdown (eth0)' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS` and `ip route show` will show `default via 192.168.1.100 dev eth0  proto static`.

Comment: I'm confused, if manager will overwrite, why edit that default old location, not manager config files? On my Linux `interfaces` file contains info only about `lo`.