# NetworkManager shared connection wrong default route

Tags: debian, networking, routing, networkmanager

I have internet on my RPi via 4G USB dongle, modem connection managed by NetworkManager (Raspbian/debian 10) using /dev/ttyUSB0. I have also OpenVPN tunnel active. Now I wanted to share this internet connection via ethernet eth0 (with Wifi AP connected to it by cable). So I added new NetworkManager connection `nmcli connection add type ethernet ifname eth0 ipv4.method shared con-name ethShared`. However when I connect anything to eth0, RPi loses internet access because of NetworkManager adding default gateway via eth0 for some reason.

```
root@rpi3meteo:~# ip route
default dev eth0 scope link src 169.254.15.88 metric 202
default via 100.94.218.129 dev wwan0 proto static metric 700
10.5.6.0/24 via 10.5.6.5 dev tun0
10.5.6.5 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.5.6.6
10.42.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.1 metric 100
100.94.218.128/25 dev wwan0 proto kernel scope link src 100.94.218.191 metric 700
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link src 169.254.15.88 metric 202
```

Also for some reason eth0 gets 2 IP addresses - 10.42.0.1 which is used also by internal DHCP server and also 169.254.15.88 (which is used in the spurious route table entry). I know 169.254.0.0/16 is link-local and for use without DHCP server, but don't know why NetworkManager configures it for connection of type "shared", which does have DHCP automaticaly provided by NetworkManager.

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:20:80:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.15.88/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 100.94.218.191/25 brd 100.94.218.255 scope global noprefixroute wwan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.5.6.6 peer 10.5.6.5/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Internet access for both RPi and Wifi clients start to work when I manually remove the spurious route via `route del default dev eth0`. However as the RPi is at a remote location, it needs to work even after a reboot without manual intervention.

I already tried to set `ipv4.never-default` parameter, but it didn't help. Also already tried to manually set the IP address range via `ipv4.addresses`. I also found a workaround with altering priority of the default route (`ipv4.route-metric` ) and dns (`ipv4.dns-priority`), but didn't have time to test it yet, however I am more interested in preventing it happen in the first place, or having NetworkManager deleting the route automatically each time the connection is activated.

```
connection.id:                          ethShared
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.interface-name:              eth0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  --
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          no
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             --
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:   --
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:        --
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:            --
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:            --
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             default
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
ipv4.method:                            shared
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       ""
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
GENERAL.NAME:                           ethShared
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        eth0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        yes
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    --
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.42.0.1/24
IP4.ADDRESS[2]:                         169.254.15.88/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            0.0.0.0
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.42.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 202
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 202
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found a solution, but at least found a workaround to get it working.
I tried to change the route metrics as advised in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529751/13946).

Setting the `ipv4.route-metric` on the `ethShared` connection to higher value (lower priority) didn't work, because it did not affect the spurious route via 169.254.15.88 at all.

So I ended up setting `ipv4.route-metric` for the 4G modem connection from default 700 to 99 (so it has now higher priority than the ethernet's 202 priority).