# Set up wired ethernet LAN to coexist with wireless WAN using NetworkManager

Tags: networking, networkmanager, wlan, lan

I have two network interfaces on a client PC, one wired, one wireless. The
wired is connected directly to a server PC running DHCP, which gives the
client PC a 10.0... address. The client PC also connects to a wireless
router, which gives it a 192.168... address. This was all set up and
detected automatically by NetworkManager. I am able to ping the server PC
and wireless router.

The problem is I want to use the wired connection as a LAN only, and the
wireless for WAN access to the wider Internet. But NetworkManager thinks the
opposite, and tries to use the LAN to go to the outside Internet. If I
unplug the cable it correctly uses wireless. But I'd like to have them both
connected at the same time.

I'm running Debian unstable if that matters.

Is there some way to configure this?

Comment: Modify your routing table so the WAN is the default route & traffic to the 10.0... network is routed through the LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out by looking at the answer to this question:

[NetworkManager changes default routing policy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203284/networkmanager-changes-default-routing-policy)

To summarize:

### Open up NetworkManager's graphical connection editor

$ nm-connection-editor

#### In the GUI:

- Click on "Wired connection 1".
- Click on the gear button for settings.
- Click on the "IPv4 Settings" tab.
- Click on the "Routes..." button.
- Check the "Use this connection only for resources on its network" box.